# when to use Synchronous and Asynchronous Request?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization

can any one explain. when to use Synchronous and Asynchronous request with example.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, asynchronous requests do not block the running environment until they get a response. This keeps your UI responsive while waiting for the response, and enables your user to use it. With synchronous requests, the UI would feel like it would be frozen.

I would say that while developing a web application, you would probably use asynchronous requests 99.9% of time.

From a software engineering stand of point, synchronous code is using one process, while asynchronous code executes a concurrent process. That is exactly how your UI is enabled to be responsive. It's like as if the asynchronous code ran as another program, if you will.